# Reading an XML file into a TreeView

Tags: c#, xml, treeview, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to load an XML file onto my GUI using a TreeView control.
However, I am using a proprietary layout for my XML file.

The XML is structured like this:

```
<ConfiguratorConfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Section>
        <Class ID="Example" Name="CompanyName.Example" Assembly="Example.dll">
            <Interface>
                <Property Name="exampleProperty1" Value="exampleValue" />
                <Property Name="exampleProperty2" Value="exampleValue" />
                <Property Name="exampleProperty3" Value="exampleValue" />
            </Interface>
        </Class>
    </Section>
</ConfiguratorConfig>
```

I'd like the output to be structured like:

```
Class "Example"
    Property "exampleProperty1"
    Property "exampleProperty2"
    Property "exampleProperty3"
```

I'm totally new to using XML.  I've been searching the web for the past few hours, and none of the results have helped.  Some have come close, but perhaps properties won't show up, or node's names won't display, etc.

I'm writing in c# in Visual Studio 2005.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through nodes using XmlDocument, you can put this demo in a Main method of a console application:

```
        string xml = @"<ConfiguratorConfig xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
<Section>
    <Class ID=""Example"" Name=""CompanyName.Example"" Assembly=""Example.dll"">
        <Interface>
            <Property Name=""exampleProperty1"" Value=""exampleValue"" />
            <Property Name=""exampleProperty2"" Value=""exampleValue"" />
            <Property Name=""exampleProperty3"" Value=""exampleValue"" />
        </Interface>
    </Class>
</Section></ConfiguratorConfig>";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);

        foreach (XmlNode _class in doc.SelectNodes(@"/ConfiguratorConfig/Section/Class"))
        {
            string name = _class.Attributes["ID"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine(name);

            foreach (XmlElement element in _class.SelectNodes(@"Interface/Property"))
            {
                if (element.HasAttribute("Name"))
                {
                    string nameAttributeValue = element.Attributes["Name"].Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(nameAttributeValue);
                }
            }
        }
```

If you're using version of .NET higher than 3.0 you can use XDocument class (recommended if you can choose).

```
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        foreach (XElement _class in xdoc.Descendants("Class"))
        {
            string name = _class.Attribute("ID").Value;
            Console.WriteLine(name);

            foreach (XElement element in _class.Descendants("Property"))
            {
                XAttribute attributeValue = element.Attribute("Name");
                if (attributeValue != null)
                {
                    string nameAttributeValue = attributeValue.Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(nameAttributeValue);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perfect!  I managed to adjust this code to populate my TreeView, and it's just what I needed.